# Auto Hotkey- script which checks if bandicam recording is "running"

Tags: windows, script, process, autohotkey

I would like to have your thoughts or help about how make this script to look **Bandicam** up **running and recording** at that moment.

I have successfully made one script which is working at short of level. I found it from Auto Hotkey’s help **forum** topic named to
["If" program is not running "then" start](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/33659-if-program-is-not-running-then-start/)

```
#SingleInstance Force
#NoTrayIcon

Process, Exist, bdcam.exe ; check to see if bdcam.exe is running.
If (ErrorLevel = 0) ; If it is not running.
    {
    Send, {F4} ; F4 is seted hotkey to start recoding prosces.
    msgbox recoding was not running.
    }

ExitApp
```

My problem is that I couldn't find any specific exe or **process** what starts or maintains *video recording*.

I watched bdcam.exe processes using **procexp.exe** program and noticed that there is only one specific change in file list in bdcam.exe.
**Starting recoding triggers** X.avi file to shown in **file list** if there aren't any files at that time Bandicam isn't recording.

*in bdcam64.bin there is not any changes when recording stage is triggered*

I don't know how to do it in code that will check that way isn't recording on/off.

You can see check images bellow, if that helps on problem solving.
[Bandicam processes and bdcam.exe file list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldzeH.jpg)

If there is any suggestions or ways to do it another way or examples to give, hit me up please.

If we can make it work it saves <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>:ing from the game to see if Bandicam is recording for sure and also capture awesome moments.

Comment: You can create a script that checks whether the newest avi-file in the recording folder  is in use (e.g. by trying to rename the file). If this is the case, the program is recording at that moment

Comment: @user3419297 yea that is good one too but. If you want to think that this is for every one not just to me who knows how to code. If somehow we can make it work as it checks from file type .avi and it won't check where is save folder, because it is created automatically when bandicam starts recoding and AutoHotKey can sniff exe's. If you have solution please can you help me, I'm new on AutoHotKey and thank you for your comment!

Comment: I cannot understand your logic, because I don't have Bandicam in my system. Does the program create a new (avi-)file in the recording folder when you press F4 to start recording? If so, in which folder?

Comment: @user3419297 yes you can choose to record it mp4 or avi file. Yes, it does create new file if you look picture what I linked to up. On green it adds it always when recoding is started. I think on AutoHotKey there is way to just sniff out file type so script don’t need to know file name or where is it created because bandicam will create it in exe just need somehow make it look it exe's proses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
#If ProcessExist("bdcam.exe")

    F1::
    Sleep, 300
       ; get the newest file in F:\
    Loop F:\*.*
    If ( A_LoopFileTimeModified >= Time )
    Time := A_LoopFileTimeModified, File := A_LoopFileLongPath
    ; MsgBox, Latest file in F:\ is `n`n%File%  
    FileMove, %File%, %File%
    If (!ErrorLevel)
    {
        ; MsgBox, The program isn't recording
        Send, {F4}
    }
    ; else
        ; MsgBox, File is busy (The program is recording)
    return

#If

ProcessExist(name){
Process, Exist, %name%
return Errorlevel
}
```

Replace

```
Loop F:\*.*
```

with

```
Loop F:\*.avi
```

if you want to check the latest avi-file in F:.

Comment: Kay I did. Problem is script will now work fine if program isn't recoding but if it is then it says "File is busy (The program is recording)" when you press F4. But F4 key is also binded hotkey to bandicam to stop and start recording. It can't stop recoding because it keeps saying "File is busy (The program is recording)". IT won't allow bandicam to stop recoding and start new one.

Comment: Then use another hotkey to start recording if the program isn't recording. I replaced it with F1. Try it again,

Comment: This fixed the problem, thank you @user3419297 very much to made this problem solved! I'll be on touch if I face another problem thank you again for your wonderful help.

Comment: Hello @user3419297, I have another problem which is stopping the recoding after session/window exits full screen mode. There is one solution, but that won't work on multiscreen if resolutions are different. Can you please have look  [link] (http://superuser.com/questions/1143334/autohotkey-script-to-press-button-after-video-socket-exits-full-screen-mode/1143771#1143771). Thank you again!

Comment: Hello, can you try to solve this please it went too complicated.live broadcast sites which stops recording after 2nd screen Chrome window exists full screen. gauge "like you YouTube full screen button does". After broadcast ends video player, exists the full screen mode then script alerts Bandicam recoding program pressing F4 key to tell stop recoding. It is on my secondary screen. In this code [link](http://superuser.com/questions/1143334/autohotkey-script-to-press-button-after-video-socket-exits-full-screen-mode/1143771#1143771) it works only when window is active whole time.