# AutoHotkey- script to press button after video socket exits full screen mode (Chrome)

Tags: windows, google-chrome, script, autohotkey

When video socket (Google Chrome) exits full screen mode, I need to:

- Send, {F4} ; to stop video recording on bandicam
- It needs to track/looking **1st.** monitor (*Looking sites title perhaps*)

Does anyone know how to do this with Autohotkey?

Tips...
Active window size changes when video socket exits full screen.

Monitoring can be possible at looking tittle tag from Chrome

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
#SingleInstance, force
SetTitleMatchMode, 2


loop
{
    If Winexist(" - Super User")
    {
        WinGet, styles, Style
        if(styles & 0xC40000)
        {
            if isfull
            {
                send {F4}
                isfull=0
            }

        }
        else
        {
            isfull=1
        }

    }
sleep 500
}
```

This version should work on every Monitor and only in a Tab that ends with " - Super User"

Comment: I edited the code, hopefully that works, also the "- Super User" can be any part of the Tab title

Comment: Normally it should work on all Monitors, or do you have Monitors with different size?

Comment: The newer version should definatly work because it doesnt need the window size

Comment: @user7079855 do you mean the Tab automatically stopps fullscreen? or what exactly do you mean by not active

Comment: you can try WinExists(...) instead of WinActive(...) if thats what you are looking for

Comment: have you also changed the A argument from winget to WinExist(" - Super User")?

Comment: Then its not possible to do other stuff while that script is working, or at least not easy to code

Comment: Settimer check 250 activates the check method every 250 milliseconds and tooltip x was only for texting purposes, it prints a x in a small box under the mouse because i had nothing to check when F4 was pressed

Comment: What info shows Window Spy when this window is active?

Comment: What do you mean by "this window"?

Comment: I put this question to user7079855. Your code works for me with Google Chrome when it exits the full screen mode. It could be, that user7079855 doesn't use the correct title(-segment) or the script requires more details in order to identify the window.

Comment: @user3419297 that could be because I changed the code 1 hour age

Comment: why are you writing a other "answer" with the exact code like my thing and say thats a better answer?

Comment: @ShulkerHD Thank you for solving this and providing excellent solution and sorry to being unclear. Update your answer to this I'm going to accept your answer after. I'm going to delete mine after....

Comment: why update mine, the version you wrote doesnt do anything better. It detects If there is one window from super user and if there is any other window thats chrome, you are not checking one window, you check if there are two windows each with one parameter